# Pandas row index optimized for a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example dataframe as follows

```
   p1   p2  p3  score
0   1   a   t1  0.408718
1   1   a   t2  0.694732
2   1   a   t3  0.001077
3   1   b   t1  0.250646
4   1   b   t2  0.877506
5   1   b   t3  0.033305
6   2   a   t1  0.735524
7   2   a   t2  0.055166
8   2   a   t3  0.579875
9   2   b   t1  0.579199
10  2   b   t2  0.785301
11  2   b   t3  0.339372
```

`p1`, `p2` and `p3` are parameters. What I would like to do is to select the optimal row with p1 and p2 values with the maximum average score based on `p3`.

For example in the given dataframe, this function should return either one of the rows 9,10,11 since the mean of p3 scores `(0.579199, 0.785301, 0.339372)` = `0.567958` is the maximum value I can get for any given set of `p1` and `p2`.

My try so far (using pandas groupy) is as follows

```
temp = []
for eachgroup in df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).groups.keys():
    temp.append(df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).get_group(eachgroup)['score'])

temp1 = []
for each in temp:
temp1.append(each.mean())

maxidx = temp1.index(max(temp1))

temp[maxidx].index
```

Returns me the following output

```
Int64Index([9, 10, 11], dtype='int64')
```

However, this is very inefficient and works only for smaller dataframes. How can I do the same for bigger dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `transform`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).score.transform('mean').idxmax()
9
```

If instead you want the combination of `p1` and `p2` that corresponds with this maximum:

```
>>> df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).score.mean().idxmax()
(2, 'b')
```

The latter would be helpful if you wanted to view the range that created the maximum average:

```
df.set_index(['p1', 'p2']).loc[(2, 'b')]

       p3     score
p1 p2
2  b   t1  0.579199
   b   t2  0.785301
   b   t3  0.339372
```

Comment: Thats a very elegent oneliner. Thanks.

Comment: If you want *all* the rows that correspond to the maximum, [Wen's answer is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51971340/3483203).  If you're just interested in the combination of `p1` and `p2`, you only need a single row.

Comment: One singly row would already give me the optimal values of `p1` and `p2`. So in my case, this is ok

Answer (score 6):

In your case

```
s=df.groupby(['p1','p2']).score.transform('mean')
s.index[s==s.max()]
Out[239]: Int64Index([9, 10, 11], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Upvoted, concise and efficient while maintaining clarity

Comment: Agreed. Very concise and elegent. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

oneliner: groupby p1 and p2, take the mean of the score column for each group. Get the id of the maximum value in the aggregated series.

```
df.groupby(['p1', 'p2'])['score'].agg(lambda x: x.mean()).idxmax()

>>> ('2', 'b')
```